# Extração de coluna de uma Serie Temporal no Matlab

Tags: matlab

Desejo extrair a coluna de tempo da série temporal do Matlab, mostrada na figura abaixo. Os comandos para fatiar matrizes no Matlab parecem não funcionar com séries temporais. O Matlab me da a seguinte mensagem

> > y = x(:,0)
> > Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Se no lugar de zero eu colocar 1 a série temporal é atribuída inteira a y, isto é, tanto a coluna de dados como a coluna de tempo, conforme figura.

[image: Serie Temporal]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessar o vetor tempo dela através da propriedade Time.

```
    y = x.Time;
```

Comment: Esses dados vem do Simulink. Estava importando através do bloco "TO WORKSPACE", a variável estava como "serie temporal" e mudei para "estrutura com tempo", ai consegui separar as duas colunas, mas de qualquer forma, obrigado.